# How do I solve this error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

```
data@server01:~$ ssh user@10.7.4.1 -vvv
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.7.4.1 [10.7.4.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/data/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Can you check the logfiles on the server you're connecting to?

Comment: Is the key in DOS format (DOS newlines) perhaps? E.g. try backing up the key and then "dos2unix id_rsa" and see if that fixes it. Most distros have that command or it is easily installable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's something wrong with your private key, probably the first line.

**Don't paste it into the question.**

How did you generate the private key?  Can you try creating a new one?  (Remember that they come in pairs so only do this if you can change the public key at the other end too.)

Answer (score 0):

The key is most likely either SSL or in PuTTY format. It's not compatible with Linux ssh client/server.

Answer (score 0):

Right it is the format - looks like a Putty generated key.

To properly cut/paste a puttygen key see here:
http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-ssh-keys-authentication-with-putty-and-linux-server-in-5-quick-steps

However - you are not sshing from a Windows computer, are you? Looks like you are sshing from a Debian-based server to a private IP. Are you trying to use the puttygen keys on another host? Why do that instead of 'ssh-keygen'?

I am curious what you are trying to do here. Can you give more detail?